# Jruby and ffi: Function 'xmlFirstElementChild' not found in [libexslt.so]

Tags: jruby, nokogiri, ffi

On a ubuntu server, with everything installed (checked against another pc where this works just fine) When trying to run warble on one of my jruby projects, I get this error:

```
Function 'xmlFirstElementChild' not found in [libexslt.so]
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/ffi.rb:112:in `create_invoker'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:98:in `attach_function'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:96:in `each'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:96:in `attach_function'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-java/lib/nokogiri/ffi/libxml.rb:116
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-java/lib/nokogiri/ffi/libxml.rb:31:in `require'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require' 
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-java/lib/nokogiri.rb:11
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-java/lib/nokogiri.rb:36:in `require'/
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/jruby-1.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
[...]
```

all libraries and required gems seem to be there.
Google didn't help, and the strange thing is that on other pc this works fine...

danilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of libxml2 are you using?

I had this same problem on OSX (leopard) which ships with libxml-2.6.x.  I installed libxml-2.7.3 and the error went away.  More info here: http://wikihub.berkeley.edu/x/zgXNAQ

Comment: thanks, we actually have libxml version 2.6.x, I'm going to install the 2.7.x version and test it out (I'll need to compile it as the ubuntu package contains the 2.6.x one... maybe we need to dist-upgrade?!)

Comment: ...and it worked! thanks again (I'm trying to reach 15 reputation to mark your answer as useful :) )

Comment: Just a note that this issue has been fixed in the source tree, and will be released in v1.4.3, hopefully this weekend. Thanks for using Nokogiri!